# How to give alert when user clicked on disabled input field?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two input fields i.e. VimeoLink and YTLink, I am trying to **disable YTLink until and unless the VimeoLink input field is empty**, and **if the user clicked on the disabled YTLink input field an alert needs to be shown**, but an alert is not working!

I have **tried several solutions for alerts** like -

```
$("YTLink").click(function (evt) {
  console.log('disabled input clicked!');
});​
```

```js
//for disabling input on first
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById('YTLink').disabled = true;
});
checking
if vimeolink input is empty or not
$('input[name=vimeoLink]').change(function() {
  if (document.getElementById('vimeoLink').value !== '') {
    document.getElementById('YTLink').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('YTLink').disabled = true;
  }
});
//alert on click YTLink input
var container = document.querySelector('#YTLink');

container.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('disabled input clicked!');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group last mb-3">
  <label for="name">VimeoLink</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="vimeoLink" id="vimeoLink">
</div>

<div class="form-group last mb-3">
  <label for="name">YTLink</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control formcheck" placeholder="" name="YTLink" id="YTLink">
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing a `#` in `$("YTLink")`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen `var container = document.querySelector('#YTLink');` I have already done this, did you mean in example snippet ?  in this one - `$("YTLink").click(function (evt)` ?

Comment: yes, it should be `$("#YTLink")`

Comment: I tried, though this doesn't help, btw I got the answer below, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ans is **NO**. Disabled inputs don't fire click event. Solution is wrap your input with `div`, and fire click on that div using `class` or `ID`.

Example:

```js
//for disabling input on first
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById('YTLink').disabled = true;
});
//checking
//if vimeolink input is empty or not
$('input[name=vimeoLink]').change(function() {
  if (document.getElementById('vimeoLink').value !== '') {
    document.getElementById('YTLink').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('YTLink').disabled = true;
  }
});
//alert on click YTLink input
var container = document.getElementById('tempdisable');

container.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var inp = document.getElementById('YTLink');
  if (inp.disabled) {
    console.log('disabled input clicked!');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group last mb-3">
  <label for="name">VimeoLink</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="vimeoLink" id="vimeoLink">
</div>

<div class="form-group last mb-3">
  <label for="name">YTLink</label>
  <div id="tempdisable">
    <input type="text" class="form-control formcheck" placeholder="" name="YTLink" id="YTLink">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since disabled control elements can't have events bound to them, you'd need to bind an event to an ancestor element and make a check to see whether the target was the input.

You can then go on to check if it's disabled, and if so, show your alert:

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    if(e.target.id == "Travellerpaymentinfo_cc_number" && e.target.disabled){
       alert("The textbox is clicked.");
    }
});
```